# Where is the official udev source and other dev information?

Tags: udev

I'm trying to find a changelog or commit history for `udevd`, but I can't seem to find the official source. Where is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mailing list archives: 
http://www.spinics.net/lists/hotplug/

Git repository:
http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/hotplug/udev.git;a=summary

Documentation:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/
It's also in the source.

Answer (score 14):

udev was merged into the systemd source tree at some point. ([Mailing list article](http://lwn.net/Articles/490413/))

Mailing list:

- http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

Git repository (and directories):

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/libudev

Documentation:

- http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/udev.html

Comment: `udev` was merged into `systemd` after release of version `182`.