# How to debug a device that changes from /dev/ttyUSB0 to /dev/ttyUSB1 at will?

Tags: centos, usb, devices

I have a device plugged to a CentOS server that changes randomly from /dev/ttyUSB0 to /dev/ttyUSB1 and vice versa.

The device I'm trying to connect is [this one](http://goo.gl/euq3Ik).

How can I debug this?

Comment: `changes randomly`? what do you mean?? i doubt that it changes while the device is plugged in.

Comment: What type of device is this? You can force it to stay to a particular device using `udev` but something else sounds suspicious, as if the device is faulty and is getting erroneously re-detected.

Comment: @umläute, actually it does.

Comment: @slm, it's a usb to RS485 converter. I'll try to force the device address on udev. Will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: does the device get reset while plugged in? what does `dmesg` tell you?

Comment: See this Q&A for `udev` resources: [Where is the official udev source and other dev information?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31983/where-is-the-official-udev-source-and-other-dev-information/78421#78421)

Comment: You don't say what model/brand you're using but this might be useful none the less: http://www.sealevel.com/support/article/AA-00524

Comment: @slm, I added a link to the device's website. Thanks for the sealevel info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device probably gets disconnected while you're using it; check your `dmesg` output after it changed to `/dev/ttyUSB1`. When it gets disconnected, the old name `/dev/ttyUSB0` is not immediately released (I'm not sure why, maybe because some program still has an open handle to the device file...?). Then the device reconnects but now the kernel can't reuse this name so it uses the next free name, so you now it's `/dev/ttyUSB1`.

Possible reasons for this could be a defective USB device or a defective USB port.