# What is udev "urbnum"?

Tags: udev, documentation

When [making a query to the udev system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters), one attribute that can show up is the `urbnum` ie:

```
ATTRS{urbnum}=="538"
```

I've looked through [the documentation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31983/where-is-the-official-udev-source-and-other-dev-information), but cannot find any mention of it. Are the attributes documented somewhere else? Performing a [google query](http://google.com/search?q=urbnum) on the term returns scattered results.

What is the `urbnum`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per [`struct usb_device`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/usb.html#c.usb_device):

```
urbnum

    number of URBs submitted for the whole device
```

where `URB` stands for `USB Request Block`. An `URB` consists of all relevant information to execute any USB transaction and deliver the data and status back.
See also:
[Kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/URB.txt)
[USB Urbs](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-13-sect-3.shtml)